# Need help identifying this yellow-flowering shrub/bush

Tags: identification, shrubs, flowering

Recently purchased a home in Denver, CO and this shrub/bush is in the front yard. It has smaller green leaves and yellow flowers that are currently blooming in the April-May time frame. It’s a woody bush about 4-5 feet tall and high.

Any help identifying is greatly appreciated!

[image: yellow shrub]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have either a golden currant (**[Ribes aureum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribes_aureum)**) or its very close relative the clove currant (**[Ribes odoratum](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=m110)**). Both are native to Canada and most of the US. Like most other currants, golden and clove currant berries are edible, but best when cooked with sugar, like black currants. Both species are also fragrant. Given the rounded leaves in your photo, I suspect that you probably have a cultivar of one of these species (the leaves are much pointier in both species). A cultivar would almost certainly be shorter and narrower than the sizes I listed above.

For more information, the US Forest Service has better photos than Wikipedia along with a nice [write-up](https://www.fs.fed.us/wildflowers/plant-of-the-week/ribes_aureum.shtml) about the golden currant.

Comment: Thank you! I'm confident based on the information you provided I have something in this family.